# MCP23S17 IOCON register values do not update correctly

Tags: spi, microchip, mcp23s17

I am currently testing the functionality of a Microchip [MCP23S17](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf) SPI 16-bit GPIO port expander for an application with a number of external inputs & outputs. The initial configuration of an MCP23S17 has been keeping me busy with quite a struggle for nearly 3 days straight. I have read a number of forum posts on this topic and have ruled out a number of possible causes that seem to be common in other topics regarding the MCP23S17.

First things first, I am aware of and have addressed the following possible concerns:

- Initial register mapping on device power-up (default is BANK = 0). I am writing to the correct register address for the IOCON register, which is mirrored at addresses 0x0A and 0x0B.
- SPI bus configuration and parameters seem to be OK, since I am able to read the port values correctly in the device's default state (for example, I read a "1" on a particular pin that I am applying a voltage to on the circuitry).
- The CS and RESET signals are driven by the PIC (no external resistors for these pins).
- There are decoupling capacitors where they should normally be.

Some more info on the setup:

- The MCU controlling the port expander is a PIC32MX450F256L running at
  40 MHz.
- The SPI bus is configured for 5 MHz clock speed. More bus settings are:

  ```
  SPI1CONbits.MODE32 = 0u;
  SPI1CONbits.MODE16 = 0u;
  SPI1CONbits.CKE = 1u;
  SPI1CONbits.CKP = 0u;
  SPI1CONbits.MSTEN = 1u;
  ```
- The hardware address pins are currently all wired to GND, with the
  intention of using the hardware address decoding functionality. The
  final intended application will be where multiple port expanders are
  used, each assigned a different hardware address (I am aware of the
  errata about pin A2, which will come into play when the final
  application is being developed).

This is the circuit for the MCP23S17 as currently used in my test setup:
[image]

I am trying to configure the MCP23S17 as follows, via the IOCON register:

- BANK = 1 (segregated register mapping)
- MIRROR = 1 (mirror interrupt pins)
- SEQOP = 1 (sequential operation disabled)
- HAEN = 1 (hardware addressing enabled)
- INTPOL = 1 (active-high interrupt)

The rest of the bits in the IOCON register are cleared.

The above bits make up a register value representation of **0xEA**. However, when I write this value to the IOCON register and read the register value back again, the values differ.

Here are some examples of IOCON values that I tried to write and read back again to confirm that the register has been set correctly. I am 100% sure that I am using the correct addressing scheme (since this change in the IOCON register changes the register mapping scheme from paired mode to segregated mdoe). The IOCON values are read from the 2 addresses where I am expecting them to be (**0x05** and **0x15** in this case) and are consistent between IOCONA and IOCONB. Between each write and read combination to/from the IOCON register, I performed a hardware reset of the device to ensure that the state of the device is always the same when attempting to write to the IOCON register. Herewith the examples used for testing:

- Write **0xEA** => reads back **0xC6**

In this case, the actual configuration now has the ODR bit set (open-drain interrupt output) as well, while maintaining the INTPOL bit as set. This does not make sense, since having ODR = 1 will override the INTPOL bit and essentially configure it the opposite to what I would like it to be configured to.

- Write **0xE8** => reads back **0xE1**

In this case, the actual configuration seems to have the HAEN bit cleared, while (very weirdly) having the unimplemented bit in bit position 0 set.

The latter example is particularly concerning, since it seems to blatantly ignore the setting of one bit (HAEN) and actually sets a bit that is not even used in the IOCON register. To test this further, I tried the following values for the IOCON as well (and now it gets even weirder):

- Write **0xFF** => reads back **0xFE** or sometimes **0xFD**
- Write **0xFE** => reads back **0xFD** or sometimes **0xFE**
- Write **0xFD** => reads back **0xF9** or sometimes **0xFC**
- Write **0xFC** => reads back **0xF9** or sometimes **0xFC**
- (...the list goes on, so I have just mentioned a few examples
  here...)

It is as if the IOCON register just cannot be set to what I want it to be set to, which is incredibly frustrating. Am I missing something obvious here? Has anyone ever seen such behaviour from this IC? Any assistance in this regard will be infinitely appreciated, as this is becoming an extremely frustrating and critical issue in the current development cycle that is wasting a tremendous amount of time with no promising results.

Comment: This is a very well-written and detailed question, except for the missing introduction :-) Can you add a few lines explaining what an MCP23S17 is and include a simple schematic. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract, and yours is almost excellent.

Comment: A link to the appropriate datasheet would also be helpful.

Comment: How hard would it be to try running your SPI at a lower speed?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind comment, TonyM. Good suggestions - I have added a few more lines of info together with a schematic.
@ElliotAlderson: Link to datasheet added.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead: I have tested this with a slower SPI clock speed and there is no difference in the result - exactly the same thing happens at a lower SPI clock speed.